# Linux unable to open X server

Tags: bash, perl, ghostscript

I am creating some images using the following script.  The script runs and creates the file. However I am getting an error. If I ssh into the server using the -Y it I do not receive the error.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile=/home/pi/my_image.png -q -r200 -g200x100 -
display: unable to open X server `' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/426
```

I am using perl and I did set the `EVN{DISPLAY}'"0.0"` still errors. However I actually don't want to display the file.  Only create them and store the file in the `/home/pi/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE` to the options.  These are standard best-practice flags to use when outputting to file.

Comment: Actually, I'd disagree with these being 'best practice'. -dSAFER has nothing to do with file output, it prevents PostScript programs from accessing most of the filesystem. Fundamentally this is used to prevent programs creating or delteing files. -dNOPAUSE simply means 'don't pause between pages', and -dBATCH means 'exit when complete' instead of returning to the interactive prompt.

Comment: I tried adding `-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE`, still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why that is happening to you.  Only the devices that start with x11 should require an X-server.  What are you redirecting into the gs command?  Could it be the application that you are redirecting thats requiring the display?  Try passing an image name instead of - to attempt to rule out ghostscript.